# Не могу изменить стиль первого элемента

Tags: html, css

Есть такой код

```css
.user-data select:first-child {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="user-data" name="gender">
        <option>Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Нужно выбрать первый элемент `<select>` тега, *и задать ему стили*, но как видно из моего кода , *селектор не выбирает первый элемент*.

Как *выбрать* **первый элемент** и задать ему нужные стили?

Отмечу что без класса `.user-data` CSS  работает правильно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь искать `select` в `select`:

```
.user-data select:first-child
```

Поиск по классу:

```
.user-data:first-child
```

Поиск по тегу:

```
select:first-child
```